# oh-storm and zend server: Cannot accept external Zend Debugger connection: Cannot evaluate expression 'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])'

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, zend-server, zend-debugger

I try to debug with PhpStorm (2016.3.1) and Zend Server 9.01 with Z-Ray. Everything has the newest Version and installed locally onto my MacBook. 
For making it simple, I created a new directory, with one file (index.php) in it.

Into PhpStorm into

Prefferences - Language&Frameworks - PHP - Servers, there is one Server:
Host: zf3-test2.dev
Port: 10088
Debugger: Zend Debugger

Prefferences - Language&Frameworks - PHP - Debug - Zend Debugger
Debug Port: 10137
Settings broadcasting port: 20080
Can accept external connection: checked
Ignore Z-Ray system requests: unchecked

Into my /etc/hosts I set
127.0.0.1 zf3-test2.dev

Into Zend Server I created a virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:${port}>
  DocumentRoot "/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/zf3-test2/"
<Directory "/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/zf3-test2/">
  Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ServerName ${vhost}:${port}

# include the folder containing the vhost aliases for zend server deployment
Include "${aliasdir}/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

So now, when i call into the browser the address http://zf3-test2.dev:10088 , my site opens and works fine.

I read this instructions:
http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/content/debugging_in_phpstorm_using_zend_server.htm

I created a breakpoint.

I activate into PhpStorm "Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections". 
Then I right klicked onto the index.php and choosed "Open in Browser - Chrome"

The file opens into chrome, and there I klicked into the z-Ray line onto the Debug sign, and choosed "Debug current page".

I shortly get a window with this text:
Die Seite zf3-test2.dev funktioniert nicht
zf3-test2.dev hat keine Daten gesendet.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Into PhpStorm into Event Log I get two times the same message:
Cannot accept external Zend Debugger connection: Cannot evaluate expression 'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])'

Then into chrome, the page will be shown.

So no Debugging is possible at the moment.
What can I do to fix it?

Thanks for help and greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when trying to set up Zend Debugger with Zend Server 9.01.  I found a bug on youtrack [WI-34697](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34697) that gave me the idea to try upgrading to zend server 9.1 and that worked for me. Unfortunately the upgraded process deletes all of your zend server settings, so I don't know if there was a bug in zend server or a problem with my configuration.